# How to connect association from another controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am working on my rails dashboard and I am trying to figure out a way to render my photos to show the add new photo path using rails.

A user has a profile which a profile has many albums, photos, videos

Albums route looks like so

```
resources :albums do
  resources :photos
end
```

For the dashboard a dashboard has many profiles and a profile belongs to dashboard.

scenario:

I have a model, controller, etc called video and I am able to create a new video using

```
<%= link_to 'Create a new Video', new_video_path %>
```

When I place the above code in my dashboard view the link shows and works correctly. It works for every other single resource also.

When I try to add

```
<%= link_to 'New Photo', new_album_photos_path(@album) %>
```

I cannot get the nested resource link to work. Album works fine but photos which is nested under album does not. I get the error

> undefined method `new_album_photos_path'

Any solutions on how to fix or resolved this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is probably new_album_photo_path (non-plural photo), not 100% sure

run `bundle exec rake routes` it will output all of the patterns and method names built from routes.rb

Comment: I've tried that and it gives me error no routes matches. Not sure why this is not working

Comment: what does `bundle exec rake routes` show in you the terminal? it should show you the correct method name - maybe album_new_photo_path ?

Comment: it shows `new_album_photo` but when visiting dashboard page I get the error `No route matches {:action=>"new", :controller=>"photos"}`

Comment: I think house9 is correct. And remember that you still have to send the @album instance to the route helper, i.e. which album do you want to add the photo to? `new_album_photo_path(@album)`

Comment: Now I think I see the problem. Adding a photo can vary because as a user your're not sure what album the photo will be added to. Is there anyway to get this to work?

Comment: I believe if you are using nested routes you need to have an album before you can create the photo, the url needs to look like /albums/:album_id/photos/new, you could have a link that says 'New Photo' but then have them select an album before going to the new photo form and don't use the rails _path method?

Answer (score 0):

config/routes.rb:

Try to replace code:

```
resources :albums do
  resources :photos
end
```

Anywhere BEFORE: 'resources :albums' or/and 'resources :photos'. Upper-level routes override your nested route. I think so...